# Incorrect Orientation of Graph in Stewart's Calculus 8E

Tags: graphing-functions, conic-sections, orientation

The problem is #27 (matching graph), and the answer is VIII. I am losing my mind trying to figure out why graph VIII is oriented to have a greater set of Z vertices when X should be the major axis for the ellipses. Please correct me if I am wrong, but should the graph be oriented so that the X vertices would be 1 unit from the origin and the Z vertices would be 1/2 units from the origin? Meaning the ellipses would be wider than it is tall. [Orientation of Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBAb4.png)

Answer (score 0):

$$ x^2 + 2 z^2 = ( x/1)^2 + ( z^2/ .7071) = 1 $$

is an elliptic cylider with semi-axes $ (1,0.7071) $ in $x,z $ directions  respectively.It is correct, x-axis size should be more than in z-direction.

Comment: I completed overlooked that it would be .7071 as the distance for the z vertices, but thank you both for verifying that the x-axis vertices should be further out. The image really threw me for a loop (especially the dotted ellipse in the negative portion of the y-axis).

Comment: Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

The section is an ellipse with equation $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{z^2}{b^2} =1$ with semi-major (resp minor) axis length $a=1$ and $b=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\approx 0.7$ (not $1/2$); thus, there is a slight **compression** along the $z$ axis. It is true that, on image VIII, there are no units ... but, for me, nothing that can be considered as an error.